# Filter array by Object key regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array that looks like

```
const arr = [
{img2: "assets1.png - Copy.png"},
{img2: "lime.jpg"},
{img2: "ginalee.jpg"}
{img2: "cb.jfif"}
{code: "blob:http://localhost:3000/d2c4641a-8586-4bb8-9a14-21b6712856ff", key: "img2", value: "cb.jfif"}
{code: "blob:http://localhost:3000/b406ceb8-92f4-4bbd-9eef-7db7d103b1e3", key: "img2", value: "lime.jpg"}
{code: "blob:http://localhost:3000/28130041-347f-49d9-b30d-72e26c9a6dda", key: "img2", value: "ginalee.jpg"}
{code: "blob:http://localhost:3000/d0d3e9aa-8791-419d-8585-f6c878b161e6", key: "logo", value: ""}
{code: "blob:http://localhost:3000/187977de-6a8f-4815-b3e2-01bfa818bcb7", key: "logo", value: "OIPYYPYPEVF.jpg"}
{code: "blob:http://localhost:3000/dee69b85-6d13-4f81-ba5b-d8db5708d9c8", key: "logo", value: ""}
{code: "blob:http://localhost:3000/676b0366-f30e-4653-9716-ab0ebf4155a2", key: "logo", value: "image (
5).png"}
]
```

I need to get rid of the ones that say img2 (or really /img[0-9]/) and just about every variation of

`arr.filter((f)=>Object.keys(f).includes(...))` isn't working.

any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `.some` of the keys contain `img`:

```
arr.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(key => !key.includes('img')))
```

Comment: I do it everytime myself but the result i want is rendered by !key.includes('img')

Answer (score 1):

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  for(let r in arr[i]) { 
     if(arr[i][r].match(/(img)[0-9]/ig)) { 
        arr[i][r] = arr[i][r].replace(/(img)[0-9]/ig, "");
      }
   }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work to ignore all img[0-9]:

```
arr.filter((val) => Object.keys(val).every((key) => !key.match(/^img[0-9]+$/i)));
```

This will get all the keys for each individual object and evaluate with `every` if the key name matches the regex to get the negated value (meaning any value matching the regex will return `false` causing .every to stop iterating and return `false` to the `.filter` function and thus removing those values.